# How to show details in tooltip or qtip and allow event modification

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am implementing fullcalendar, i wanted to show the details of an event onclick.. from example i am able to display it onclick or onmouseover, but box disapears when i move my mouse pointer.

I am beginner to jquery and fullcalendar.. Some ideas for the above problem will be very helpful..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read some documentation.

For instance qtip supports "hide" (fixed) option which would allow (if set to TRUE) your tooltips to stay visible even if you move your mouse out.

```
hide: { when: 'mouseout', fixed: true }
```

Please refer to this URL for more information:

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/#hide

Comment: Thank you.. After going through documentation.. i will give response